# Split lines to words then save as a new file

Tags: powershell

Say I have a text file test.txt in C drive.

```
On the face of things, we seem to be merely talking about text-based files, containing only 
the letters of the English Alphabet (and the occasional punctuation mark).
On deeper inspection, of course, this isn't quite the case. What this site
offers is a glimpse into the history of writers and artists bound by the 128 
characters that the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII) 
 allowed them. The focus is on mid-1980's textfiles and the world as it was then, 
but even these files are sometime retooled 1960s and 1970s works, and offshoots 
 of this culture exist to this day.
```

I want to split all lines to words then save it as a new file. In the new file, each line only contains one word.

Thus the new file will be:

```
       On
       the
       face
       of
       things
       we
       seem
       to
       ....
```

The delimiter is a white space and please skip all punctuation marks.

Comment: Have you made any attmpt to solve this yourself?  Can you share what you've tried and what the results were?

Comment: I am not strong on powershell, I used c# but the code is not concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't even tried. The next time I'm voting for closed question. Powershell uses 99% of c# syntax and "all" .Net classes are available, so if you know c#, you will come far in PowerShell by using 5 minutes on google and trying some commands.

```
#create array
$words = @()

#read file
$lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\in.txt")

#split words
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $words += $line.Split(" ,.", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
}

#save words
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\out.txt", $words)
```

In PowerShell you could also do it like this:

```
Get-Content .\in.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Split(" ,.", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) 
} | Set-Content out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Text = @'
On the face of things, we seem to be merely talking about
text-based files, containing only  the letters of the English Alphabet
(and the occasional punctuation mark). On deeper inspection, of
course, this isn't quite the case. What this site offers is a glimpse
into the history of writers and artists bound by the 128  characters
that the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII)  
allowed them. The focus is on mid-1980's textfiles and the world as it
was then,  but even these files are sometime retooled 1960s and 1970s
works, and offshoots   of this culture exist to this day.
'@

[regex]::split($Text, ‘\W+’)
```

Comment: Good answer, but for certain words like "isn't" it will split on the apostrophe. That seems like less than desirable results, since "isn" and "t" are not words. In my answer, I used a regex to strip out all of the special characters first, and then match words after that.

Comment: Good point. Transforming isn't to isnt has issues too. Challenging problem. It may take more than a regex.

Comment: Agreed, it has its own issues, but it meets the requestor's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions, that will:

- Remove special characters
- Parse words based on word boundaries (`\b` in regex)

Code:

```
$Text = @'
On the face of things, we seem to be merely talking about text-based files, containing only 
the letters of the English Alphabet (and the occasional punctuation mark).
On deeper inspection, of course, this isn't quite the case. What this site
offers is a glimpse into the history of writers and artists bound by the 128 
characters that the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII) 
 allowed them. The focus is on mid-1980's textfiles and the world as it was then, 
but even these files are sometime retooled 1960s and 1970s works, and offshoots 
 of this culture exist to this day.
'@;

# Remove special characters
$Text = $Text -replace '\(|\)|''|\.|,','';
# Match words
$MatchList = ([Regex]'(?<word>\b\w+\b)').Matches($Text);
# Get just the text values of the matches
$WordList = $MatchList | % { $PSItem.Groups['word'].Value; };
# Examine the 'Count' of words
$WordList.Count
```

Result looks like:

```
$WordList[0..9];
On
the
face
of
things
we
seem
to
be
merely
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother splitting the string, since you write the result back to a file anyway. Just replace all punctuation (and perhaps parentheses as well) with spaces, replace all consecutive whitespace with newlines, and write everything back to a file:

```
$in  = 'C:\test.txt'
$out = 'C:\test2.txt'

(Get-Content $in | Out-String) -replace '[.,;:?!()]',' ' -replace '\s+',"`r`n" |
  Set-Content $out
```